# I cannot make a file explorer

Tags: php, html, css, file

I have a problem. Indeed, i want to create a file explorer in PHP but the files must be downloable. I manage to display the tree structure but not the download. Someone have an idea ?

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Comment: and take the [tour]

Comment: Just a tip for the future: Your underlying question is fine (although it probably could have been answered with some prior research, as you're not the first person to try and make download function in PHP!!) but the way it's worded is very poor - it doesn't focus on the real issue (especially not in the title) and also includes no relevant code or context to indicate what you had tried or where you got stuck. That's why your question is closed and heavily downvoted. read the guides in the links above before posting further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP to download a file you must send a header to trigger a download.
Here you have an example:

```
$filename="MyFilePathAndExtension";
//Define header information
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: 0");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filename).'"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
header('Pragma: public');
```

Take into account that if you want this to work, any "echo" must be called **AFTER** the header part or else the header wont be sent and thus, there won't be any download triggered.

Comment: Glad it worked :)
Make sure to mark this as the solution for anyone that might have the same issue on the future.